# How to disable Togglebutton from extended combobox class

Tags: c#, wpf, class, combobox

I have a class that extends `Combobox`. In this class I can **ONLY** disable  the `togglebutton`. I still want users to click into the `combobox` and type something in to filter its contents.

If you know any other way to destroy the `togglebutton` please let me know (as long as it doesn't involve recreating the template - I've tried and failed and the generated `combobox` template code is to large to dump in stackoverflow so I can't solve it that way. )

In the beginning I wanted to be able to toggle the `togglebutton` (if there less than 10 item left in the filter allow a user to click the `togglebutton` to show the list of items if there are more the togglebutton would disappear) . At this point I'll take any solution that shrinks, hides, moves, intentionally breaks, removes, buries alive, replaces either the togglebutton or the mouse on click event that tells the combobox that it should show its popup or anything in between that will stop this action.

This is my third question trying to find something that will work. Honestly any suggestions would be helpful (just no copy and edit the template please go to my other question where I ask help on how to implement that solution)

```
using Analytics_Module.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Analytics_Module.UI_Components
{
    class MultiselectFilteredComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        ////
        // Public Fields
        ////

        /// <summary>
        /// The search string treshold length.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// It's implemented as a Dependency Property, so you can set it in a XAML template 
        /// </remarks>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumSearchLengthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "MinimumSearchLength",
                typeof(int),
                typeof(MultiselectFilteredComboBox),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(3));

        ////
        // Private Fields
        //// 

        /// <summary>
        /// Caches the previous value of the filter.
        /// </summary>
        private string oldFilter = string.Empty;

        /// <summary>
        /// Holds the current value of the filter.
        /// </summary>
        private string currentFilter = string.Empty;
        public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
   where T : DependencyObject
        {
            // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
            if (parent == null) return null;

            T foundChild = null;

            int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                // If the child is not of the request child type child
                T childType = child as T;
                if (childType == null)
                {
                    // recursively drill down the tree
                    foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                    // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                    if (foundChild != null) break;
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
                {
                    var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                    // If the child's name is set for search
                    if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                    {
                        // if the child's name is of the request name
                        foundChild = (T)child;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // child element found.
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return foundChild;
        }
        ////
        // Constructors
        //// 

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the FilteredComboBox class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// You could set 'IsTextSearchEnabled' to 'false' here,
        /// to avoid non-intuitive behavior of the control
        /// </remarks>
        public MultiselectFilteredComboBox()
        {

        }

        ////
        // Properties
        //// 

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the search string treshold length.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The minimum length of the search string that triggers filtering.</value>
        [Description("Length of the search string that triggers filtering.")]
        [Category("Filtered ComboBox")]
        [DefaultValue(3)]
        public int MinimumSearchLength
        {
            [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
            get
            {
                return (int)this.GetValue(MinimumSearchLengthProperty);
            }

            [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(MinimumSearchLengthProperty, value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a reference to the internal editable textbox.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>A reference to the internal editable textbox.</value>
        /// <remarks>
        /// We need this to get access to the Selection.
        /// </remarks>
        protected TextBox EditableTextBox
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox") as TextBox;
            }
        }

        ////
        // Event Raiser Overrides
        //// 

        /// <summary>
        /// Keep the filter if the ItemsSource is explicitly changed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="oldValue">The previous value of the filter.</param>
        /// <param name="newValue">The current value of the filter.</param>
        protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
        {
            if (newValue != null)
            {
                ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(newValue);
                view.Filter += this.FilterPredicate;
            }

            if (oldValue != null)
            {
                ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(oldValue);
                view.Filter -= this.FilterPredicate;
            }

            base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Confirm or cancel the selection when Tab, Enter, or Escape are hit. 
        /// Open the DropDown when the Down Arrow is hit.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Key Event Args.</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// The 'KeyDown' event is not raised for Arrows, Tab and Enter keys.
        /// It is swallowed by the DropDown if it's open.
        /// So use the Preview instead.
        /// </remarks>
        protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Tab || e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                // Explicit Selection -> Close ItemsPanel
                this.IsDropDownOpen = false;
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
            {
                // Escape -> Close DropDown and redisplay Filter
                this.IsDropDownOpen = false;
                this.SelectedIndex = -1;
                this.Text = this.currentFilter;
            }
            else
            {
                if (e.Key == Key.Down)
                {
                    // Arrow Down -> Open DropDown
                    this.IsDropDownOpen = true;
                }

                base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
            }

            // Cache text
            this.oldFilter = this.Text;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Modify and apply the filter.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Key Event Args.</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Alternatively, you could react on 'OnTextChanged', but navigating through 
        /// the DropDown will also change the text.
        /// </remarks>
        protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Down)
            {
                // Navigation keys are ignored
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Tab || e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                // Explicit Select -> Clear Filter
                this.ClearFilter();
            }
            else
            {
                // The text was changed
                if (this.Text != this.oldFilter)
                {
                    // Clear the filter if the text is empty,
                    // apply the filter if the text is long enough
                    if (this.Text.Length == 0 || this.Text.Length >= this.MinimumSearchLength)
                    {
                        this.RefreshFilter();
                        this.IsDropDownOpen = true;

                        // Unselect
                        this.EditableTextBox.SelectionStart = int.MaxValue;
                    }
                }

                base.OnKeyUp(e);

                // Update Filter Value
                this.currentFilter = this.Text;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Make sure the text corresponds to the selection when leaving the control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">A KeyBoardFocusChangedEventArgs.</param>
        protected override void OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //this.ClearFilter();
            //int temp = this.SelectedIndex;
            //this.SelectedIndex = -1;
            //this.Text = string.Empty;
            //this.SelectedIndex = temp;
            //base.OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(e);
        }

        ////
        // Helpers
        ////

        /// <summary>
        /// Re-apply the Filter.
        /// </summary>
        private void RefreshFilter()
        {
            if (this.ItemsSource != null)
            {
                ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ItemsSource);
                view.Refresh();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clear the Filter.
        /// </summary>
        private void ClearFilter()
        {
            this.currentFilter = string.Empty;
            this.RefreshFilter();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Filter predicate that will be applied to each row in the ItemsSource.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">A row in the ItemsSource.</param>
        /// <returns>Whether or not the item will appear in the DropDown.</returns>
        private bool FilterPredicate(object value)
        {
            MultiSelectDropDownListEntry tmp = (MultiSelectDropDownListEntry)value;

            // No filter, no text
            if (value == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // No text, no filter
            if (this.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            // Case insensitive search
            return tmp.Name.ToString().ToLower().Contains(this.Text.ToLower());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way.

I added this to the class

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        (((this.GetVisualChild(0) as Grid).Children)[1] as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton).IsEnabled = false;
    }
```